# OpenCV how to grab the real time frame and not the next frame?

Tags: opencv, real-time, rtsp

I realized that when I use OpenCV to grab videos (cv2.VideoCapture('rtsp://...')) in a rtsp url, actually I am getting everyframe of the stream and not the real time frame.

Example: If a video has 30fps and 10 seconds long, if I get the first frame and wait 1 second to get the next, I get the frame number 2 and not the real time frame (it should be frame number 30 or 31).

I am worried about these because if my code take a little longer to do the video processing (deep learning convolutions), the result will always be delivered later and not in real time.

Any ideas how can I manage to always get the current frame when I capture from rtsp?

Thanks!

Comment: there is the possibility to use grab and receive functions, but this isnt working for all devices (not sure about the reasons). Typically, the most reliable way is to run the capturing in a separate thread to capture ALL frames as fast as possible and just discard all which will not be processed.

Comment: you can make use of data ingestion tools like Apache Kafka or RabbitMQ for this

Answer (score 0):

This is not about the code. Many IP cameras gives you encoded output(H.265/H.264).

When you used `VideoCapture()` , the output data of the camera is decoded by the CPU. Getting delay as you mentioned also such as between 1 sec and 2 sec is normal.

### What can be done to make it faster:

1. If you have a GPU hardware, you can decode the data via on it. This
   will give you really good results(according to experiences by using
   latest version of NVIDIA gpus: you will get almost 25 milisecond
   delay) To achieve that on your code, you need:

   - CUDA installation
   - CUDA enabled OpenCV installation
   - [VideoReader class](https://docs.opencv.org/4.3.0/db/ded/classcv_1_1cudacodec_1_1VideoReader.html) of OpenCV
2. You can use `VideoCapture()` with FFMPEG flag, FFMPEG has advanced methods to decode encoded data and this will give you probably most faster output which you can get with your CPU. **But this will not decrease time much.**

Comment: Thanks Yunus for the answer, but I am no worried with speed. I am worried in getting the real time frame when I read it and not the frame in the sequence (the next from the last frame captured). I think that the comments above may help to solve (read in separate thread). Regards!